# React Audio Player does not play or find file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the [React Audio Player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player)

In my App.js I have imported the package and then do:

```
    <ReactAudioPlayer
      src="../my_audio_file.ogg"
      autoPlay
    />
```

This seems to be fine, everything renders correctly and I get no errors. However, it does not let me play my file, it's all grayed out, I guess the player cannot find the file.

My question now is whether I did anything wrong with regards to the file path or have to consider anything else. The file is located one level above the App.js file and has exactly that name.

Comment: Could you check in the network tab of your browser in what the request to the file resulted? 204? 404?

Comment: I did check it just now (in Chrome Dev Tools under network, I hope this is correct?), and there is nothing (although there should be, as it's autoplay). When I click play it gives me still nothing. The player is also grayed out, so my click is just not registered, which explains that it doesn't make a network request in the first place.